# Can an LC tank circuit alone produce oscillations?

Tags: oscillator

The circuit below is the Hartley oscillator circuit. I simulated it in Multisim to understand exactly how oscillations occur.

While doing so I just separated the tank circuit (from transistor base and collector) then applied 12V DC voltage across it (across tank as shown below). Now also the tank circuit is producing oscillations (even without the transistor).

What I expected from the tank circuit is different (I thought oscillations would not occur), but it produced sinusoidal oscillations.

Explain me how it is possible? (I know about resonance but I'm unable to match it with what I see because I thought resonance occurs only when AC is applied -- correct me if I am wrong)

Can I reproduce that tank circuit practically? If not, why?

Please, explain to me how to look intuitively at it.

(This is not my homework, if my way of asking this question appears like that, it is only because of my English).

Here is my circuit:

[image]

Comment: The way this question is presented it appears to be 100% homework. This site is not a homework solutions site. Folks here will help ... IF you show some initiative to try taking first steps toward solution. Explain specifically what you have done and then ask pointed questions about where or why you got stuck. Only then will someone be able to help nudge you toward a solution.

Comment: To other people wanting this question to remain closed: I don't think this question is blatantly homework (it *may* be, but it doesn't look necessarily so). Assuming it is not homework, the question is rather interesting, IMO, although rather basic. Moreover, the closing reason doesn't match. What the OP is asking is pretty clear. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought oscillations will not occur

Think of an LC tuned circuit as a pendulum. At rest it produces no oscillations but if you push it a bit it will swing back and forth at its resonant frequency no matter how small or big in amplitude the swing is. Pushing the pendulum is the same as applying a voltage or current step to the LC.

> Please explain me how to look intuitively at it.

Hopefully I've done that. If not, regard an LC circuit like a metal-rule placed on the edge of a table. If you hit it it oscillates but dies down because of air resistance and friction losses.

Comment: "Think of an LC tuned circuit as a pendulum. At rest it produces no oscillations but if you push it a bit" this is very intuitive sir, but small dout that is: pushing a pendulum is equal to applying dc voltage,but dc voltage keeps pushing the circuit one side only na(means pushing a pendulum continously towards one side, how can pendulum oscillates now).

Comment: For a parallel tuned circuit a push would be a step in DC current. For a series tuned circuit the push can be a step in voltage.

Comment: this is what I expected, something intuitive now going into my mind, thank you sir.

Comment: A motor driving a rubber band connected to a flywheel is a good analogy. Run the motor and it rapidly gets to (say) 1000 rpm. The rubber band starts twisting and slowly accelerates the flywheel. Some time later the flywheel is up to 1000 rpm but the elastic band has still got a thousand twists. Those twists are actual stored energy. From here, the flywheel carries on accelerating up to 2000 rpm (no twists left). Then it starts the downward cycle and reaches zero speed before accelerating back to 2000 rpm. Inductor = elestic band. Capacitor = flywheel. Series circuit, rpm = voltage.

Answer (score 5):

Your circuit model contains no lossy elements, so the response to the initial turn on transient never dies out. There's a transient because the capacitor will be assumed to have 0 voltage, and the inductors 0 current,  before time 0.

If you add realistic series resistance values to your inductor and capacitor models, you should see the oscillations die quickly.

Another way to reduce the turn on transient effect is to replace the dc source with a step source with a long turn- on ramp, like maybe 100 cycles of the tank resonance frequency.

Comment: I added resistor before cap for the same circuit above, now no oscillations produced. you said about occurence of decaying oscillations but What is the effect of DC voltage on tank, why Dc can't provide current needed to charge capacitor once again.

Comment: Calculate the expected Q from your added resistance. The higher it is, the longer you'll have to run the sim to see the effect.

Comment: ok, i will work on calculation from now only.